# deferencing the int malloc pointer

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, pointer-arithmetic

```
int main()
{

    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    int rslt, n;
    float sum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *tri = (int*)malloc(n * 3 * sizeof(int));
    if(tri == NULL){
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%d\n", *(tri[0]));
```

when I am referencing the tri pointer then it is showing the error.
invalid type argument of unary '*'.
thanks for the answer.
The above part is clarified but I have another issue. but I have another issue

```
int main()
{
    
    int rslt, n;
    float sum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *tri = (int*)malloc(n * 3 * sizeof(int));
    if(tri == NULL){
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &(tri[j]));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            sum += tri[j] / 2;
            printf("%d %d\n",sum,tri[j] / 2);
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",sum);


    return 0;
}
```

when I am printing the tri[j] it is showing some garbage value.

Comment: You need either `printf("%d\n", *tri);` or `printf("%d\n", tri[0]);` but either way, the allocated memory has not been initialised.

Comment: `tri` is a pointer, but `tri[0]` is already derefencing that pointer to get the first value in the "array". In fact, `tri[0]` is exactly the same as `*(tri + 0)` (or plain `*tri`).

Comment: With that said, `malloc` doesn't initialize the memory it allocates in any way, its contents will be *indeterminate* (look at it as garbage).

Comment: Finally, [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) And the consensus seems to be "no, do *not* cast the result".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `tri` has the type `int *` due to this declaration

```
int *tri = (int*)malloc(n * 3 * sizeof(int));
```

Pay attention to that you allocated an uninitialized memory.

The expression `tri[0]` has the type `int`. And you are trying to apply the dereference operator to the expression of the type `int`

```
*(tri[0])
```

So the compiler issues an error.

Instead you could write

```
int *tri = (int*)calloc(1, n * 3 * sizeof(int));
```

and then write either

```
printf("%d\n", tri[0]);
```

or

```
printf("%d\n", *tri);
```

These for loops

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &(tri[j]));
    }
    printf("\n");
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        sum += tri[j] / 2;
        printf("%d %d\n",sum, tri[j] / 2);
    }
}
printf("%d\n",sum);
```

are incorrect. There are used an incorrect conversion specifier `%d` instead of `%f` with the variable `sum` and incorrect expressions for indices. You need to write

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &(tri[3 * i + j]));
    }
    printf("\n");
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        sum += tri[3 * i + j] / 2;
        printf("%f %d\n",sum, tri[3 * i + j] / 2);
    }
}
printf("%f\n",sum);
```

Comment: what if I want to take input then how will I do that?

Comment: @nabeelkhan If I have understood you correctly then you can write for ( int i = 0; i < 3 * n; i++ ) scanf( "%d", tri + i );

Comment: I am doing this but when I am printing the value then it is showing some garbage value

Comment: @nabeelkhan You can print the array like for ( int i = 0; i < 3 * n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", tri[i] );

Comment: Thanks buddy for the answer. But if n=1 then also do I need to specify tri[3*i+j] ?

Comment: @nabeelkhan In general you should do that. If for example n will be changed your code will be still correct.

Answer (score 0):

The array expression `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)` - given some address value `a`, offset `i` elements (*not bytes!*) from that address and dereference the result, so

```
*tri == *(tri + 0) == tri[0]
```

The expression `tri[0]` has type `int`, which is why the compiler is complaining when you write `*(tri[0])`; the operand of the unary `*` operator must have a pointer type.

So in your `printf` statement you would use *either* `*tri` *or* `tri[0]`.  The type of either expression is `int`.

As others have said, `malloc` does not initialize the allocated memory, so the value of `tri[0]` may be anything.  You could use `calloc` instead, which initializes the memory to all-bits-zero:

```
int *tri = calloc( n, sizeof *tri );
```

In C you do not need to cast the result of `malloc`, `calloc`, and `realloc`<sup>1</sup>, and most of us will advise you to not do so.  Similarly, since the type of the *expression* `*tri` is `int`, the result of `sizeof *tri` is the same as `sizeof (int)`.  This way you don't have to worry about keeping types straight between the declaration, the cast, and the `sizeof` expression, so you're less likely to make a mistake.

---

1. This is not the case in C++, but if you're writing C++ you shouldn't be using the C `*alloc` functions anyway.